# Outcomes from multiple IF combinations in a spreadsheet

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am basically after a formula that would check what I have already done manually before I start using my data. Bit of a logic problem...

[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eCTfTBsqNgY144M4EtLHuQIdPpp-pE3BOXcZeTt76vY/edit#gid=2124498406)

Please see the link to my Google Sheet that has the mark scheme to a piece of coursework I am trying to assess. The coursework has the elements and each one can be marked at Level 1 Pass, Level 1 Merit, Level 2 Pass, Level 2 Merit and Level 2 Distinction, with different combinations available and different weights for Column C available (noted on the mark scheme as C.2P5, C.2P6 and C.2D3 - these mean Level 2 pass and Level 2 Distinction (higher than L2 Pass is also acceptable)).

In column D you can see our manually logic, we'd really appreciate a formula to produce the same (or correct!) values in column E.

Answer (score 0):

**formula you are looking for is:**

```
=IF(OR(A2="U", B2="U", C2="U"), "U",
 IF(AND(A2="L2D", B2="L2D", C2="L2D"), "L2D",
 IF(AND(A2="L2P", B2="L2P", C2="L2P"), "L2P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2P", OR(B2="L2M", B2="L2D"), C2="L2P"), "L2P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2P", OR(B2="L2M", B2="L2D"), C2="L2M"), "L2P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2M", OR(B2="L2M", B2="L2D", B2="L2P"), C2="L2P"), "L2P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2M", B2="L2P", C2="L2M"), "L2P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2D", OR(B2="L2M", B2="L2D", B2="L2P"), C2="L2P"), "L2P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2D", B2="L2P", C2="L2M"), "L2P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2M", OR(B2="L2M", B2="L2D"), OR(C2="L2M", C2="L2D")), "L2M",
 IF(AND(A2="L2P", OR(B2="L2P", B2="L2M", B2="L2D"), C2="L2D"), "L2M",
 IF(AND(A2="L2D", B2="L2P", C2="L2D"), "L2M",
 IF(AND(A2="L2D", OR(B2="L2M", B2="L2D"), OR(C2="L2M", C2="L2D")), "L2M",
 IF(AND(A2="L1P", OR(B2="L1P", B2="L1M"), OR(C2="L1P", C2="L1M")), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L1P", B2="L2P", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L1P", B2="L2M", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L1P", B2="L2D", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="L1M", A2="L2P", A2="L2M", A2="L2D"), B2="L1P", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="L1M", A2="L2P", A2="L2M", A2="L2D"), B2="L1M", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="L1M", A2="L2P", A2="L2M", A2="L2D"), B2="L2P", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="L1M", A2="L2P", A2="L2M", A2="L2D"), B2="L1D", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="L2P", A2="L2M", A2="L2D"), B2="L2M", C2="L1P"), "L1P", 
 IF(AND(A2="L2M", B2="L2P", C2="L2D"), "L2M",
 IF(AND(A2="L2P", B2="L2P", C2="L2M"), "L2P",
 IF(AND(A2="L1M", B2="L1P", C2="L1M"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L1M", B2="L2D", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2P", B2="L2D", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2M", B2="L2D", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L2D", B2="L2D", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L1P", B2="L2D", C2="L1M"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(A2="L1M", B2="L2M", C2="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(AND(OR(A2="L2P", A2="L2D"), B2="L1P", C2="L1M"), "L1P", 
 "L1M"))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Thanks works like a treat! Just to confirm (I haven't trawled through the logic), this works out the logic from the mark scheme? It's not just designed to match up to my manual entry? The reason i ask is that i can't believe I did 200+ permutations with no errors myself! :P @player0

Comment: @MrLFenner let's hope you did because I couldn't understand your mark scheme at all xD

Comment: Ah ok! We think we have noticed an error in our workings, and therefore your formula, on the sheet we shared, highlighted, line 166, following the rules should be an L1P... Don't suppose you could locate the section of the formula that would check this? @player0

Comment: @MrLFenner mark them (and correct the output) and I can check it out and correct this formula

Comment: highlighted in green for you - but again, this is only on our ability to mentally work this out!

Answer (score 0):

**array formula variant - paste it in G1 (or any cell in the first row):**

```
={"GRADE"; ARRAYFORMULA(
 IF(LEN(A2:A) * LEN(B2:B) * LEN(C2:C), 
 IF((A2:A="U") + (B2:B="U") + (C2:C="U"), "U",
 IF((A2:A="L2D") * (B2:B="L2D") * (C2:C="L2D"), "L2D",
 IF((A2:A="L2P") * (B2:B="L2P") * (C2:C="L2P"), "L2P",
 IF((A2:A="L2P") * ((B2:B="L2M") + (B2:B="L2D")) * (C2:C="L2P"), "L2P",
 IF((A2:A="L2P") * ((B2:B="L2M") + (B2:B="L2D")) * (C2:C="L2M"), "L2P",
 IF((A2:A="L2M") * ((B2:B="L2M") + (B2:B="L2D") + (B2:B="L2P")) * (C2:C="L2P"), "L2P",
 IF((A2:A="L2M") * (B2:B="L2P") * (C2:C="L2M"), "L2P",
 IF((A2:A="L2D") * ((B2:B="L2M") + (B2:B="L2D") + (B2:B="L2P")) * (C2:C="L2P"), "L2P",
 IF((A2:A="L2D") * (B2:B="L2P") * (C2:C="L2M"), "L2P",
 IF((A2:A="L2M") * ((B2:B="L2M") + (B2:B="L2D")) * ((C2:C="L2M") + (C2:C="L2D")), "L2M",
 IF((A2:A="L2P") * ((B2:B="L2P") + (B2:B="L2M") + (B2:B="L2D")) * (C2:C="L2D"), "L2M",
 IF((A2:A="L2D") * (B2:B="L2P") * (C2:C="L2D"), "L2M",
 IF((A2:A="L2D") * ((B2:B="L2M") + (B2:B="L2D")) * ((C2:C="L2M") + (C2:C="L2D")), "L2M",
 IF((A2:A="L1P") * ((B2:B="L1P") + (B2:B="L1M")) * ((C2:C="L1P") + (C2:C="L1M")), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L1P") * (B2:B="L2P") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L1P") * (B2:B="L2M") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L1P") * (B2:B="L2D") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(((A2:A="L1M") + (A2:A="L2P") + (A2:A="L2M") + (A2:A="L2D")) * (B2:B="L1P") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(((A2:A="L1M") + (A2:A="L2P") + (A2:A="L2M") + (A2:A="L2D")) * (B2:B="L1M") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(((A2:A="L1M") + (A2:A="L2P") + (A2:A="L2M") + (A2:A="L2D")) * (B2:B="L2P") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(((A2:A="L1M") + (A2:A="L2P") + (A2:A="L2M") + (A2:A="L2D")) * (B2:B="L1D") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(((A2:A="L2P") + (A2:A="L2M") + (A2:A="L2D")) * (B2:B="L2M") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P", 
 IF((A2:A="L2M") * (B2:B="L2P") * (C2:C="L2D"), "L2M",
 IF((A2:A="L2P") * (B2:B="L2P") * (C2:C="L2M"), "L2P",
 IF((A2:A="L1M") * (B2:B="L1P") * (C2:C="L1M"), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L1M") * (B2:B="L2D") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L2P") * (B2:B="L2D") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L2M") * (B2:B="L2D") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L2D") * (B2:B="L2D") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L1P") * (B2:B="L2D") * (C2:C="L1M"), "L1P",
 IF((A2:A="L1M") * (B2:B="L2M") * (C2:C="L1P"), "L1P",
 IF(((A2:A="L2P") + (A2:A="L2D")) * (B2:B="L1P") * (C2:C="L1M"), "L1P", 
 "L1M")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))),))}
```